# Многомерный масив по значению ключа

Tags: php, массивы, api

Как можно записать цену в переменную по значению ключа,
например BTC, ETH, LTC см. скрин: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/auep7k8qppbia5b/shot_190705_190356.png

Есть вот такой код, и работает он на самом деле хорошо,
единственный минус тут -- привязка к позиции [18] т.е. сегодня на 18 месте может быть Dogecoin, а завтра Сatcoin и нужно будет переписывать...

```
<?php
$tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=19');
$data = json_decode($tick, TRUE);

$bit = $data[0]["price_usd"];
echo "<b>Bitcoin:</b> ".$bit."<br>";

$dogecoin = $data[18]["price_usd"];
echo "<b>Dogecoin:</b> ".$dogecoin."<br>";
?>
```

Можно конечно все перебрать foreach и вывести, но нужно именно запихнуть в переменные, что бы потом обращатся к ним.

Прошу помощи у более опытных товарищей :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем ассоциативный массив, комбинируя массив ключей, которые берутся из значений ключей `symbol` исходного массива и массив исходных значений. Далее импортируем переменные из полученного массива - в текущее пространство:

```
<?php
$tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=19');
$data = json_decode($tick, true);

extract(
    array_combine(
        array_map(
            function ($itm) {
                return $itm['symbol'];
            },
            $data
        ),
        $data
    )
);

echo "<b>Bitcoin:</b> " . $BTC["price_usd"] . "<br>";
```

Comment: Отлично работает, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

используйте `array_column()` со всеми аргументами, если кроме `price_usd` вам ничего не требуется

```
$data = array_column($tick, 'price_usd', 'symbol');
echo $data['BTC'];
```

Comment: Требуется, но за вариант все равно спасибо! На досуге почитаю про эту ф-цию :)